# COMP + MOVE Program

Tags: batch-file, compare, dos, move

I am looking for a program that will compare all the files in Folder A with all the files in Folder B (loop), and if the program finds that the files are the same, it will move the one from Folder A to Folder C and the one from Folder B to Folder D - leaving behind only the files that have differences in Folder A and B.

The program I have below does 90% of this and works quite well despite being quite simple. The code that I haven't been able to write yet is the movement of the file from Folder B to Folder D as I can't seem to get how to reference the file that was compared out of Folder B to have it moved.

```
@echo off

FOR %%G IN ("C:\USERS\YOUL\AUTOMATION\FOLDER_A\*.xlsx") DO (
    Echo N | COMP %%G "C:\USERS\YOUL\AUTOMATION\FOLDER_B\*.xlsx" 
    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
           MOVE %%G "C:\USERS\YOUL\AUTOMATION\FOLDER_C"
    )
)
```

As example, this code should compare Test.xlsx from FOLDER A with Test.xlsx from FOLDER B. If the files are different, do nothing (i.e. leave them in their folders). If the files are the same, MOVE Test.xlsx from FOLDER A --> FOLDER C (this is being handled by code) and MOVE Test.xlsx from FOLDER B --> FOLDER D (this is my problem area).

From my PoV - it doesn't seem like the program knows how to reference %%G out Folder B so when I have tried this, I could only manage moving the entire Folder B to Folder D which is not what I want.

Hope I have provided enough information. I am looking for an easy solution, nothing complex is required for such a simple task I believe.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, if this does, what you want to do, 
maybe you can give it a try?

```
@ECHO OFF
:Firstline
SET FOLDERA=C:\USERS\YOUL\AUTOMATION\FOLDER_A
SET FOLDERB=C:\USERS\YOUL\AUTOMATION\FOLDER_B
SET FOLDERC=C:\USERS\YOUL\AUTOMATION\FOLDER_C
SET FOLDERD=C:\USERS\YOUL\AUTOMATION\FOLDER_D

FOR %%G IN ("%FOLDERA%\*.xlsx") DO (
    ECHO N | COMP "%%~G" "%FOLDERB%\%%~nxG"
    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
      MOVE "%%~G" "%FOLDERC%\%%~nxG"
      MOVE "%FOLDERB%\%%~nxG" "%FOLDERD%\%%~nxG"
    )
)

CHOICE /C YN /M "Continue?" /T 5 /D Y
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO :EOF
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :Firstline
```

Edit: 
now this script can also loop - with a 5 sec-pause. 
you can edit the pause by changing the value after "`/T`"

Comment: BaBa - I must say this is very good. You provided something simple and easy to understand that covers exactly what was asked. Many thanks for this! I should probably spend some time around understanding how you came up with the solution so that I can at least learn from this :)

Comment: Thanks. :) You're welcome. Please feel free to mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

search the web for "doublekiller".
this Little Programm can compare filenames or just size and checksum. after analysis you can check first doubles and move them, after that you can check last doubles and move them

of course this would involve some manual work, but it would do the Job

hope it helps

EDIT: sorry just saw you Need a batch-file, but maybe it helps nevertheless

Comment: Thanks for your input, Mech. I will take it on board and check out this program - could be good to have options but I will still try to get this code developed in any case. Thanks!